# LED circuit parallel

Tags: led, parallel, series

I have SMD LEDs of 5 watts each having 6500kelvin with 9-12volts forward voltage with 900-1050 mA operating current and 1100lm@500. I have put 3 LEDs in parallel and connected it parallel to my ACxDC adaptor having input 100-240v at 50/60hz at 0.8A and output of 12volts at 1500mA. I had connected 5 LEDs with a fan in parallel earlier on another adaptor but the adaptor blew off. Now I have connected only 3 LEDs without any fan in the circuit and there are 2 computer fans blowing on the LEDs still the adaptor gets too hot. Will this one also blow out or I need to change the circuit or adaptor?
An earlier circuit with the same 3 LEDs in series is working for almost a year properly!

Comment: Please post a schematic, with manufacturer and manufacturer's part number on the parts. Otherwise you're expecting people here to draw the schematic in their heads as well as to help you. Thanks.

Comment: let me see 3 LEDs in parallel ... each drawing up to 1050 mA ... that makes it  3150 mA in total ..... you finish this thought

Answer (score 1):

Your LEDs are drawing too much current for the adapter to handle.

When you put 3 LEDs in parallel, the total current is the sum of the three currents. So in your case it adds up to up to 3150 mA at 12 V.

Your power supply is only rated to 1500 mA, so you are trying to draw twice as much current as specified.

You need a beefier power supply to make this work safely. Add in the fans you are powering and you might need something like 3.5 A of current capability.

For 5 LED, it would turn into 6 A.

As you did this wrong, I'm wondering if you are providing a means to limit the current for each LED, you might overload them too if you are just connecting them to the 12 V.

Comment: Thanks! So may I request for an alternate circuit, my first 8x10W = 80W LEDs are working since 2 years in a combination of a series and parallel circuit. Since I have two of these adaptors, can I rewire in some way and add some resistors on LEDs etc for it to work?

Comment: @KamleshBarot connecting two power supplies in parallel is often not a good idea as there is a voltage mismatch between the two and that might cause problems. I'm afraid your best choice is to get a correct wattage power supply for your project.